# Vulkan texture error except when using blender texture

Tags: graphics, textures, blender, vulkan, gltf

I created a Vulkan application that was able to render GLTF models using a library called "TinyGLTF". I then made a new application on a new device then copied and refactored the code but now i am getting visual errors with the textures.

I create the GLTF models by creating a model in blender then setting the base colour (in the material properties section) to a image texture then exporting the model as a gltf file.

when creating the model if i create an image inside of blender and edit in the texture paint section, then use this image there is no error.

Also if i export this texture that i made inside of blender as a png and try to use it in the method that gives the errors, it now works.

I think it may have something to do with how blender creates the images.

Example 1:

**This is what the model looks like in blender (What it should look like)**

[image: This is what the model looks like in blender (What it should look like)]

**This is what the model looks like in my renderer**

[image: This is what the mode actually looks like in my renderer]

Example 2:

**This is what the model looks like in blender (What it should look like)**

[image: This is what the model looks like in blender (What it should look like)]

**This is what the model looks like in my renderer**

[image: This is what the mode actually looks like in my renderer]

the images that i tried to use that failed were PNGs as were the images that i created inside blender that were successful

I am not sure what to try.

On my old device the old project rendered the textures correctly, both systems were running arch linux but my new device is using an integrated amd gpu as opposed to my old device's dedicated Nvidia gpu.

Comment: How are we supposed to help when you've posted zero code and no reproducer? The bug could be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, it was a really simple mistake.

After loading in the gltf model's data I make 2 variables for each image to store the height and width. I accidentally got these 2 variables mixed up which caused the errors. Just swapping the variables around has fixed the errors.

Thanks for the responses.